# kafka leaders and Isr are not defined

Tags: apache-kafka

We have strange behavior about what we see in described Kafka information

We can see that replicas are defined

But all leaders are `NONE` , and also `Isr` is empty

```
 $HOME/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo01:2181 --describe

Topic:car_list_abort    PartitionCount:30   ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:segment.bytes=8763524700,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
    Topic: car_list_abort   Partition: 0    Leader: NONE    Replicas: 3424,3425,3426    Isr: 
    Topic: car_list_abort   Partition: 1    Leader: NONE    Replicas: 3425,3426,3421    Isr: 
    Topic: car_list_abort   Partition: 2    Leader: NONE    Replicas: 3426,3421,3422    Isr: 
    Topic: car_list_abort   Partition: 3    Leader: NONE    Replicas: 3421,3422,3423    Isr: 
    Topic: car_list_abort   Partition: 4    Leader: NONE    Replicas: 3422,3423,3424    Isr: 
    Topic: car_list_abort   Partition: 5    Leader: NONE    Replicas: 3423,3424,3425    Isr:
```

what could be the reason for that , and how to resolve it?

**Dose Kafka partitions reassignment can solved this situation?**

Comment: Are the brokers running fine? Have you tried restarting them?

Comment: why you think restart will solved the problem ?

Comment: Leaders are NONE means the controller is not electing leader. So it could be some issue with the cluster. Or there is no controller in the cluster. Is the Zookeeper ensemble running fine and reachable? What are the Active controller count metrics saying?

Comment: can you please give me more details about "What are the Active controller count metrics saying" ?

Comment: how to check controller in the cluster.?

Comment: lets say we want to simulate this behavior on other helty cluster , is it possible  ? ( I mean to cause NONE on other kafka cluster for investigation )